# Cannot read property 'addEventListener' of null

Tags: javascript, chrome

Estoy creando una extension de Chrome para analizar el código HTML de una página y según lo que encuentre el script, reproducir un sonido, pero al subirlo a Chrome me tira error: **Cannot read property 'addEventListener' of null**.

Primero les muestro mi popup.js y abajo mi popup.html.

No se si debo cambiar algo del manifest. La verdad estoy buscando el error pero no lo entiendo, espero que puedan ayudarme, es mi primer post. Desde ya gracias

````
document.getElementById("boton").addEventListener("click", myFunction);

function myFunction(){
  console.log('asd');
}


function myFunction() {
  var txt;
  var comision = prompt("Ingresa \n el NUMERO de comision deseado:\n (solo una)", "\nEJEMPLO: R1, R2, Q7");
  document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = txt;

  var comi;

  var comi=comision;

}

// La variable comi es la comision que el Usuario desea// 
function myFunction() {
  const text = document.querySelectorAll('script')

  for (let i=0; i < text.length; i++) 
    {
    if (text[i].innerHTML.includes('Cupo disponible')) 
    { 
        let url = chrome.runtime.getURL('note.mp3')
        console.log(url)

        let a = new Audio(url)
        a.play();
    }
  }
}```



//Este es mi popup.html//

</pre><!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<h2>Ingresa tu comision deseada</h2>

<button id="boton">Click aqui</button>


<p id="demo"></p>


<script src="popup.js"></script>

</body>
</html>
</pre>
````

Answer (score 1):

He encontrado varios errores en tu JavaScript. Tienes varias funciones con el mismo nombre. 
A la sentencia:

const text = document.querySelectorAll('script')

Le falta el punto y coma.

Tu if dentro del bucle if te devuelve un Undefinied

```
if (text[i].innerHTML.includes('Cupo disponible'))
```

Te paso el archivo rectificado. Las 2 primeras funciones les he cambiado el nombre
para evitar conflictos, te he añadido un console.log para que controles la variable del if(y se vea que funciona)

```
document.getElementById("boton").addEventListener("click", myFunction);

function myFunction0(){
  console.log('asd');
}


function myFunction1() {
  var txt;
  var comision = prompt("Ingresa \n el NUMERO de comision deseado:\n (solo una)", "\nEJEMPLO: R1, R2, Q7");
  document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = txt;

  var comi;

  var comi=comision;

}

// La variable comi es la comision que el Usuario desea// 

function myFunction() {


  const text = document.querySelectorAll('script');


  for (let i=0; i < text.length; i++) 
    {
    console.log("Inner:" + text[i].innerHTML.value);
    if (text[i].innerHTML.includes('Cupo disponible')) 

    { 

        let url = chrome.runtime.getURL('note.mp3');
        console.log(url);

        let a = new Audio(url);
        a.play();
    }
  }

}
```

Espero haberte servido de ayuda